# Вывод обёртки-ссылки через views

Tags: drupal

пожалуйста помогите решить проблему с выводом из views

в drupal7 при помощи cck и views я сделал что-то похожее на ленту новостей. то есть выводятся несколько блоков, каждый из которых содержит картинку, текст и строку с некоторым адресом(для всего этого есть соответствующие поля в cck-типе материала). всю эту ленту я темизировал через шаблоны модуля views( то есть через theme: information)

проблема в том, что каждый пункт моей ленты должен быть обёрнут в тэг <a>. причем атрибут href должен содержать ту строку с некоторым адресом, о которой я писал вышее

буду благодарен за любую помощь, я в полном ступоре

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не понятно. Хоть скриншот бы или более конкретно поставьте вопрос.

Comment: вот ссылка на скрин http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/rr.jpg

на ней каждый пункт содержит:
1. картинку
2. текст
3. адрес ноды

нужно чтобы при клике по определенному пункту(картинке или тексту) пользователь переходил на определенную ноду

Comment: Хм.. Ну, могу предложить несколько извращённый вариант - во вьюсе выводим дополнительное поле id ноды, все поля исклбчаем из вывода и убираем у них ссылку(снимаем галку link field to the original piece of content), далее в настройках поля нид жмём rewrite result (перезаписать результаты)-> rewrite output -> и вводим <a href="/node/[nid]"> тут все остальные поля([title],[image] и т.д.) </a> 
Примерно так. Могу ошибаться в названиях настроек, но проверить сейчас нет возможности. Вообще, алгоритм думаю понятен. Ничего сложного. Пробуйте.

Comment: Далее к тэгу <a> допиши class и пропиши к нему стили, чтобы все ровненько отрисовывалось на странице.